# Is is possible to get a smooth transition animating an image by position?

Tags: jquery, animation, load, position

I am trying to implement a simple query animation on page load, an image (PNG with transparency) moving horizontally across the window which you can see on [this page](http://salliannputman.com/), and which uses this script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logo").animate({"left": "+=900px"}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

As you will probably see (I have tested in Firefox and Safari) the image judders as it moves across the window.  I am wondering if there is a way of making this smoother.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: I would simply speed it up. There is no good reason I know for that slide to be longer than 500, which will likely make jitter not noticeable.

Comment: js is all client side too. even if you make it smoother for you there's no way to know how everyone else is experiencing it. My machine ran your site fine.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of programming for the browser... Ughh

As someone here stated, reduce the animation time to like no more than 1000 ms so that the jitteriness is less noticeable.

You can look into CSS webkit transitions, but those will only work on browsers such as safari and chrome.